# How to create a rpm for python application

Tags: python, rpm

I have a simple application (just one .py file), that is using cherrypy & flask-restful to present a web service. My development environment is Windows. I use Python 3.5.2 and also create and use virtualenv to work on my project.

I have a need to deploy this on Linux systems. I was asked to create a "RPM" for this so that it can be installed and run on Linux machines.

I have googled and read several pieces of documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/builtdist.html
- http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/packaging/

But I'm very unclear on the steps that needs to be done to deploy this on a Linux system. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Not all linux systems use RPM. What is wrong with just a `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: I am needing a RPM for CentOS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a mini demo structure output by `tree` command, `color_print` is the package name and directory

```
.
├── color_print
│   ├── color_print.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

Here is an example `setup.py` for demo

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='color_print',
    version='0.1',
    description='Color String',
    url='http://github/xxxx/color_print/',
    author='Joe Bob',
    author_email='joe.bob@gmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['color_print'],
    zip_safe=False)
```

There is no need to change directory, run this one command to build rpms

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
```

Here is the output, it is that easy:

```
-bash-4.1$ find . -name "*.spec"
./build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/SPECS/color_print.spec
-bash-4.1$ find . -name "*.rpm"
./dist/color_print-0.1-1.noarch.rpm
./dist/color_print-0.1-1.src.rpm
```

In reality, you will definitely need to modify the spec files manually. and run

```
rpmbuild -ba ./build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/SPECS/color_print.spec
```

Comment: Thanks! Before I try out the steps you have very clearly outlined above, I have another question.
Would making a rpm this way, also install correct version of Python in the target systems? I need it this way...coz there is no way for me to go and install Python 3.5.2 on the CentOS target systems. It's possible that it has an older version of Python...but that is just a pain since my application would need to pick up the correct version of python executable.

Comment: @sam, do `cat /etc/redhat.release` to see which version of centos you are using, if it is version7, you might have the possibility to install by   `sudo yum install -y python35u python35u-libs python35u-devel python35u-pip`, you have to talk system admins for this option. If not, your options will be limited.

Comment: @sam, Here is comment on build rpm from virtualenv `https://www.alexhudson.com/2013/05/24/packaging-a-virtualenv-really-not-relocatable/`, The whole idea of virtualenv is opposite of yum/rpm package system. Is it possible/easy to modify your code on your centos?

Comment: thanks for the steps. Since my dev environment is Windows, I'm unable to execute "... bdist_rpm". It always come back with the error:-
"error: don't know how to create RPM distributions on platform nt" - which is an artifact of bdist_rpm.py checking for if os.name != 'posix':. Though I'm able to do "python setup.py bdist" which creates a .zip file in windows. Any way around this to create rpm in windows?

Comment: All, another update. I thought I had to bundle python, but my admin told me that it is not necessary - we should have python 3.5 installed on Centos 6 and similarly have any python package dependency installed using pip (like cherrypy etc)

Comment: @sam, `rpm` is short `redhat package manager`, you cannot create rpm in windows, you have to build in os like centos, the best bet is to create the rpm in your centos in your server, again ask your admin

Comment: @Gang I ran into the same issue. Thanks for letting me know. Going to copy files into a Docker image of CentOS.